# Django formset cleaned_data empty when submitted form unchanged

Tags: python, django, formset

I've been experiencing a weird problem, regarding Django 1.4 and formsets: when the submitted data is unchanged, the cleaned_data field of the formset is empty, even if the formset itself passes the validation.

Here is an example:

**forms.py:**

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, initial='Foo')
```

**views.py:**

```
def welcome(request):

    Formset = formset_factory(NameForm, extra=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = Formset(request.POST)
        print '1.Formset is valid?', formset.is_valid()
        print '2.Formset', formset
        print '3.Formset cleaned_data', formset.cleaned_data
    else:
        formset = Formset()
    return render_to_response('template.html', locals())
```

Although `formset` is valid, and it actually contains data, line 3 prints a list of an empty dictionary, unless I've actually changed the initial value in the field.

This seems weird to me, but I'm probably doing something wrong. Any help?

Comment: Can you show your template code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A formset renders bunch of forms as well as several hidden input fields holding info such as max number of forms. Thus a correctly POSTed formset always contains data.

And, the initial 'Foo' inside CharField `name` is the reason that formset got empty dictionary. When `empty_permitted` of a form is set to True, and all items of the form equals to its initial value, Django will treat the form as empty and set its cleaned_data to be empty dict. The `empty_permitted` defaults to False, formset will set it to True for extra forms. Thus after you clicked submit w/o editing the value 'Foo', the form instance was treated as empty, hence the formset wrapping the form got an empty cleaned_data.

Comment: Just helped me solve a wicked bug after much head-scratching – thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me. @okm is correct but it's not clear from his answer how to fix it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745343/django-formsets-confusion-validation-required-empty-permitted) for a solution:

```
class MyModelFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the code – very helpful. Ran into this issue earlier and it was quite infuriating!