# django formsets confusion (validation, required, empty_permitted)

Tags: django, django-forms

I am really finding the django formsets confusing.

I am especially having problems with the following concepts which I don't really understand:

> The formset is smart enough to ignore extra forms that were not
>   changed.

Talking about code trying to be too smart. What is this supposed to mean exactly ? Why would I even want that ?

Then, trying to understand the previous concept, I see people

> making forms in the formsets required.

This is another concept I can't get the hang of. What is a required form in a formset and why do I have to make a form required ? Again something not documented.

Then coming to my actual problem, which other people seem to have had, but they can't really explain why they've fixed it the way they've fixed it.

Why in the following example, the formset is valid, while an individual form with the same input will be invalid ?

```
import django
class MyForm(django.forms.Form):
    start = django.forms.DateField()
    end = django.forms.DateField()

data =  {
    'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',
    'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
    'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
    'form-0-start': '',
    'form-0-end': '',
}

MyFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm)
formset = MyFormSet(data)
#fee_forms[0].empty_permitted = False

print formset.is_valid()
# --- returns True ---
print formset.errors

f = MyForm({'start': '', 'end': ''})
print f.is_valid()
# --- returns False ---
print f.errors
```

Setting empty_permitted to False seems to give the expected results for me (which is for the formset to be invalid due to missing 'start' and 'end'). This is another undocumented feature ...

Would anybody spare some time to explain ?

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> > The formset is smart enough to ignore extra forms that were not changed.
>
> Talking about code trying to be too smart. What is this supposed to mean exactly? Why would I even want that?

It seems to mean — as you worked out — that "extra" forms created by the formset (with `extra=N` in your example) have `empty_permitted` set to `True`. [Have a glance at `django/forms/formsets.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/forms/formsets.py#L144) to see this happening.

`formset[0].empty_permitted` means that if `formset[0].has_changed() == False`, no further processing/validation is done. Again, [you can see this in action in `forms/forms.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/forms/forms.py#L268).

**To prevent this**, [a blog post suggests](http://www.kevinbrolly.co.uk/blog/django-model-formsets-not-validating/) defining a custom formset to use in `modelformset_factory` (or `inlineformset_factory`) which sets `empty_permitted = False`:

```
class MyModelFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False
```

I haven't tested this, but it looks legit.

As to why anyone might want this, it makes using
[`django-dynamic-formset`](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/) much simpler — you can send data for `form-0` and `form-2` and, assuming `form-1` was an extra form (*i.e.* not linked to model data), Django won't complain. If `empty_permitted` were `False` by default, you'd have to worry about skipping the blank form in your own code, or reindexing things in Javascript.