# Formset does not create new records, just updates old records

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

I have formset and form in one page, both are saved at the same time. But new records for event time are not saved, only old records are updated. Where is the problem?

formset:

```
    class EventTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = EventTime
            fields = ['start_time']
            widgets = {
                'start_time': DateTimeWidget(usel10n=True, bootstrap_version=3)
            }
EventTimeFormSet = modelformset_factory(EventTime, form=EventTimeForm, max_num=3, extra=3)
```

form:

```
class CreateEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'location', 'duaration', 'private']
```

view:

```
def create_event(request):
    event_form = CreateEventForm(request.POST or None, prefix='event')
    event_time_form = EventTimeFormSet(request.POST or None, prefix='eventtime')
    context = {
        'event_form': event_form,
        'event_time_form': event_time_form,
    }
    if event_form.is_valid() and event_time_form.is_valid():
        event = event_form.save()
        event_time = event_time_form.save()
        for obj in event_time:
            obj.event.add(event)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/event-%s' %event.id)
    return render(request, 'create_event.html', context)
```

template:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>{%csrf_token%}
    {{ event_time_form|crispy }}
    {{ event_form|crispy}}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957223/django-formset-cleaned-data-empty-when-submitted-form-unchanged) might help.